# Change app language to English by default

Tags: ios

Have done localisation to app with three languages Korean, Chinese and English and it is working correctly. But now I want my app to run with English only, even if the language is changed in settings. Please help me out with this.

Comment: So you don't want to change the language of your app?

Comment: Delete your `localisation` file and keep your device/simulator in english language

Comment: i don't want the localisation files to be deleted but if i set the language to korean in settings the app should show localisation for english

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your requirement is like this,

Open your app in Xcode and in that click on main storyboard,

[image: Storyboard File]

Then go to File Inspector and Uncheck the check boxes of localisation files,

[image: File Inspector]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i don't want to remove the localisation. according to your answer it will be removed